# What do "the more" and "the less" modify in "The more our knowledge of things is certain and particular, the less it is possible for us to feign"?

Tags: comparatives

The following is an excerpt from *The Young Spinoza: A Metaphysician in the Making*.

> (1) **The more** our knowledge of things is certain and particular, **the less** it is possible for us to feign;

What do **the more** and **the less** modify in this sentence?

I thought **the more** modified **is** and **the less** modified **feign**. But

- (2) As our knowledge of things is certain and particular more, so it is possible for us to feign less.

sounds strange.

Is it possible that **the more** modifies **certain and particular** and **the less** modifies **possible**?

Then, the sentence can be paraphrased as

- (3) The more certain and particular our knowledge is, the less possible it is for us to feign.

But, (3) is not the same as (1) grammatically. Or is it?

Comment: Your second interpretation is correct semantically.  I think it's *ok* grammatically but it would be better (I think) without the "is" before the comma.

Answer (score 3):

What we have here is not about *more* or *less* modifying anything.
Rather, this is an example of an idomatic syntactic construction, often called

- ***the `X`-er, the `Y`-er***

It does not form a normal sentence, but rather connects two phrases containing comparatives, and indicating that there is a direct correlation between changes in the first phrase and the second.
An inverse correlation is easily done by changing the valence of the comparative (*less* instead of *more*), or of the degree predicate being compared (*uglier* instead of *prettier*).

Either or both of the phrases may contain clauses, but don't need to.
There are many fixed phrases, proverbs, and common usages.
Examples:

- *The older I get, the more I enjoy life*
- *The bigger, the better* (fixed phrase)
- *The bigger they come, the harder they fall* (proverb)
- *The more carefully I consider his proposal, the less I am convinced that it's a good idea*.

In each case, a delta-x in the first phrase leads to a delta-y in the second.
What x and y indicate is the degree of whatever is compared in either phrase --
  in particular, the examples above indicate that

- *how old I am* correlates directly with *how much I enjoy life*
- *how big (something is)* correlates directly with *how good (it is)*
- *how big (an opponent) comes (at one)* correlates directly with *how hard they fall*
- *how carefully I consider the proposal* correlates inversely with *my opinion of it*

Comment: Shouldn't the phrase containing a comparative be fronted with its head
in those constructions 
("The more carefully I consider" rather than "The more I consider carefully")?
Otherwise, can't it be ambiguous which word the comparative modifies?
My textbook, for example, specifically says 
"NOT The more it is dangerous, the more I like it, BUT The more dangerous it is, the more I like it."

Comment: They both contain comparatives. And this is not a standard sentence, but a construction with two parts and no verb connecting them. It always starts with the comparative of the independent variable first, and then the comparative of the result of the independent variable. So "fronting" doesn't mean anything. You can make differently-structured comparatives, but that defeats some of the structure's purpose.

Comment: What does "variable" exactly mean? In (1), does it mean the veracity of the statement ? : 
the extent of the veracity of the statement "our knowledge of things is certain and particular"
is propotional to the extent of the veracity of the statement "it is possible for us to feign".
Is this use of "the x-er, the y-er" construction in (1) 
similar to the metalinguistic comparison in "Susan is more shy than unsocial.", 
where the veracities of the two descriptions of Susan are compared.

Comment: `X` and `Y` are the variables, because they vary. `X` is the one you start with (_The bigger they come,_ so `X` is the size of whoever is coming); that's the independent variable. `Y` is the second comparative, the one that is dependent on change in the first variable. This is just logical algebra; has nothing to do with veracity or truth or grammaticality. And it's not a regular comparative, metalinguistic or not. Regular comparatives have only one comparative morpheme and a baseline context to compare with. This construction has two comparatives and no baseline.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you by repeated questions, but this is important for me.
So far, I've learned this construction is not based on fronting. 
I assumed the movement "It is x dangerous" --> "The delta-x dangerous it is" 
(here I used "delta" as a symbol for a difference). 
But this is wrong.
But, I still don't understand how the construction works. 
Could you paraphrase the sentence (1) as you did for your examples.

Comment: I don't know what your arrow means. Entailment? That's probably the logical relation involved. It's a very common construction; A.A. Milne even wrote a children's poem using it. It starts _The more it snows, tiddely pom/The more it goes, tiddely pom/The more it goes, tiddely pom/On snowing._

Comment: I understand usual forms of the construction such as your examples. They are clear in that what quantity is propotional to what quantity. I don't understand the sentence (1). Let me ask you two questions.i) in the sentence (1) more of what corresponds to less of what? ii) is the sentence "The more it is dangerous, the more I like it" grammatical?

Comment: It should be _The more dangerous it is, the more I like it._ Generally the comparative morpheme (_more_ or _-er_) should be as close to the adjective being compared as possible, unless you are using a construction for parallel purposes; that is, you can start with _The more it is dangerous_ if you finish with _the more it is fascinating,_ which has the same construction.

Comment: So,is that a construction used in (1)?
Is the sentence (3) transformed into (1) for parallel purpose?

Comment: (3) has a problem with _the less possible_; it's unidiomatic. The better choice would be _less likely_ or _less probable_. _Possible_ is a difficult word, being a modal. And don't worry about what the adjectives are modifying; they're predicate adjectives and not attributive adjectives.

Comment: I'm confused. Could you please paraphrase the sentence (1) as you did for your examples in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here "more" modifies "our knowledge" which is apparently increasing. And "The less" modifies not "Our feign" the imaginary possession of a verb, but "our ability", in this case our ability to feign.

Comment: Elliot, although I see this is drastic as a precis, I think it boils down to *the more we know, the less we feign* and if that's so *our ability* is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

They modify nothing.  "[More](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/more?s=t)" and "[less](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/less?s=t)" are being used as nouns, hence the "the" that appears before them.  In this context, "more" as a noun means "a larger amount," while "less" as a noun means "a smaller amount."  To illustrate the noun usage, just substitute those definitions into the sentence, i.e., "The bigger amount our knowledge of things is certain and particular, the smaller amount it is possible for us to feign."

Comment: I'm afraid Dictionary.com doesn't qualify as an authority on grammar. John Lawler, a widely published Professor of Linguistics, does. // Your suggested expanded form is still not a sentence. It's best to leave 'The Xer, the Yer' as an extragrammatical idiom (a snowclone, as X and Y can be quite a few adjectives).

Comment: Yes, it is a sentence.  It's grammatical structure is that of an isocolon, a type of parallelism, specifically a bicolon, which leaves the subject-verb implied as it poses a protasis and apodosis.  A common example of this is: "The bigger, the better."

Comment: As for dictionary.com, it qualifies as an authority on words.  It, along with any other dictionary you might look in, shows definitions of "more" as a noun meaning what I said that it means and what it means in this instance.

Comment: You assume one particular definition of 'sentence' as if it were mandatory, without even nodding to other schools of thought. There's just too much of this arrogation on ELU.

Comment: You might also like to see that Dictionary.com doesn't seem to believe in determiners/determinatives: [some](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/some?s=t).